# Efficient iteration of matrix multiplication into a table

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, procedural-programming

Suppose I have a list of matrices $(A,B,C)$ and a vector $v$. I want to construct a table whose elements are sequential applications of these matrices to $v$, i.e., the first entry will be $Cv$, the second will be $BCv$, and the third is $ABCv$. An efficient way to do this should be to compute a single matrix product for each table entry; for example, after storing the second entry in the above example, I don't need to compute $BC$ to $v$ again, I just need to apply $A$ to $BCv$.

To me the natural way to code this is to use loops to iteratively define the table elements, but my understanding is that this is slow in Mathematica. How can I solve this problem, and more generally, make tables from sequential applications of an operation rather than writing down a formula in the usual table syntax?

Comment: `FoldList[#2 . #1 &, v, {C, B, A}]`

Answer (score 7):

This can be accomplished using `FoldList`.

```
Clear[f, a, b, c, amat, bmat, cmat, v]
FoldList[#2 . #1 &, v, {cmat, bmat, amat}]
```

> {v, cmat . v, bmat . cmat . v, amat . bmat . cmat . v}

---

Test:

```
amat = RandomReal[1, {3, 3}];
bmat = RandomReal[1, {3, 3}];
cmat = RandomReal[1, {3, 3}];
v = RandomReal[1, 3];


MatrixForm /@ {v, cmat . v, bmat . cmat . v, amat . bmat . cmat . v}

MatrixForm /@ FoldList[#2 . #1 &, v, {cmat, bmat, amat}]
```